# The same object in two databases, is this possible with doctrine2

Tags: php, activerecord, doctrine-orm, datamapper

I develop an application that allows to access two different ERP systems. I want to abstract away some differences, such that I can search the same entity in both systems and represent a list that contains entities of both (e.g. a list of invoices). I'm thinking about how to architect this.

One approach is using the ActiveRecords pattern, have a `Document` class that extends from `ObjectModel` and then create two subclasses that each contain the *database field to object property* mapping. I feel it is cumbersome, because these object then represent a single instance of a `Document`, and still need to handle queries that result in a collection of documents.

I never touched doctrine2, but as I'm reading about Active Record vs Data Mapper pattern, it seems that it could bring a solution to my problem. Therefore my question:

**Is it possible to have one object (here `Document`), and link two data mapper configurations to it, one for each data source ?**

Comment: Yes.  You can have multiple entity managers each of which can map the same object differently and to different databases.  Not entirely sure that this capability will meet you needs.  You will still need to query each system independently and then merge the results together.  You should spend some time with D2.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising. I will have a look at it. But the learning curve seems steep and the annotations somewhat awkward.

Comment: Yaml is the way to go.  In fact, annotations can't be used if you want different mappings for different entity managers.  And yep, there is a learning curve.  Ask yourself if  you really need objects at all.  I have been doing more and more with just plain arrays and wrapping services around them.  Are your objects going to end up being anemic?  Or do you expect to have actual domain behavior.

Comment: I evolve in the opposite direction. I wrote my code around SQL queries and associative arrays. The problem is that the knowledge about the database structure is scattered throughout the code. I look for a way to centralize it cleanly.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by *wrapping services around them*? Maybe I did not yet dive enough into OOP to get the meaning?

Comment: @cerad About objects vs arrays : it seems that doctrine also allows to query for a collection of associative arrays instead of for a collection of objects.

Comment: One way to centralize your database access is to use repositories.  All your database interaction is done via repositories.  The pattern  works for both arrays as well as objects.  So again, if your objects are not more than bunches of getters and setters then using objects might be overkill.  If they actually do stuff then great.